# How to get tablerow id dynamically in android?

Tags: android

Hello, my old code is working, but the problem is that when i am clicking tablerow it call another activty, but it not set that table row data but it setting last array data to that activity.

Means it  set the last array value to next screen activity.

```
for ( j = 0; j < dataListfeture.size(); j++)
            {

                HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();

                hm = dataListfeture.get(j);

                final TableRow tblrow = new TableRow(MainScreen.this);
                final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.featuredrow, null);
                tblrow.setId(j);
                tblrow.getId();



                featuredName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.xxName);
                featuredDistance = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.xxDistance);
                featuredVeneType = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.xxVeneType);
                featuredPhone = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.xxPhone);
                featuredAddress = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.xxAddress);

                Drawable image = ImageOperations(MainScreen.this, hm.get("url"), "image.jpg");

                featuredImage = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.xxdImage);
                featuredImage.setImageDrawable(image);

                featuredName.setText("" + hm.get("name"));
                featuredDistance.setText("" + hm.get("distance") + " mi");
                featuredVeneType.setText("" + hm.get("venuetype"));
                featuredPhone.setText("" + hm.get("phonenumber"));
                featuredAddress.setText("" + hm.get("address"));


                mapnamelist = hm.get("name");
                mapvenuelist = hm.get("venuetype");
                mapothervenuelist  = hm.get("othervenuetype");
                mapaddresslist= hm.get("address");
                mapcitylist= hm.get("city");
                mapstatelist= hm.get("state");


                tblrow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    {

                        final ProgressDialog progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(MainScreen.this, null, "Loading ....", true);
                        final Handler handler = new Handler()
                        {
                            public void handleMessage(Message msg)
                            {
                                System.out.println("search");

                                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainScreen.this, xxxxscreen.class);
                                startActivity(myIntent);
                                MainScreen.this.finish();
                                progDailog.dismiss();

                            }
                        };

                        new Thread()
                        {
                            public void run()
                            {
                                try
                                {

                                    System.out.println();


                                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);

                                }
                                catch (Exception e)
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }.start();

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an `int` array of id say `array_id[]` and after setting id to table row add that id to `array_id[]` also like

```
tblrow.setId(j);
array_id[j] = j;
```

And in onClick method do this:

```
for(int i = 0;i< array_id.length;i++)
{
    TableRow tbl_row = (TableRow) findViewById(i);
    if(v.getId() == array_id[i])
    {
        /**    Perform your Operations */
    }

}
```